# Как сопоставить значения списка и переменной?

Tags: python, list, словари

У меня есть большой JSON файл с часто  задаваемыми вопросами. Структура такая:

```
язык интерфейса ==> категория ==> вопрос
```

Получается пока так:

```
if request in FAQs[c['from']['language_code']].values()
```

Но строка

```
if request in FAQs[c['from']['language_code']].values()
```

возвращает такой список

```
[{'Вопрос 1': 'Ответ 1', 'Вопрос 2': 'Ответ 2', 'Вопрос 3': 'Ответ 3'}, {'Вопрос 4': 'Ответ 4', 'Вопрос 5': 'Ответ 5', 'Вопрос 6': 'Ответ 6'}, {'Вопрос 7': 'Ответ 7', 'Вопрос 8': 'Ответ 8', 'Вопрос 9': 'Ответ 9'}]
```

Необходимо сравнить `request` с вопросами (Вопрос 1, Вопрос 2 и т.д.).

Это возможно?

Чтобы интерпретатор как бы проверял сразу во всех словарях (элементах списка `list(FAQs[c['from']['language_code']].values())`) значение полученное от пользователя, и говорил существует ли такой вопрос.

Comment: интересно, но - непонятно... добавьте в вопрос файл и уточните, что нужно сопоставить?

Comment: можете привести [mcve] данных, пример ввода и результат, который вы хотите получить?

Comment: у меня есть JSON файл с часто  задаваемыми вопросами. Я получаю запрос от пользователя в виде вопроса. Дальше, я хочу обработать этот вопрос. Для  этого я получаю следующие словари: https://pastebin.com/BvbDrup2. У меня есть каждая категория с вложенными вопросами в виде словарей. Я хочу просто проверить существование вопроса среди ВСЕХ категорий. Как я могу такое сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я понял задачу правильно, то примерно так можно проверить, наличествует ли строка `request` в каком-то вопросе или ответе и вывести эту пару вопрос-ответ, если задан список из нескольких словарей формата вопрос-ответ:

```
qa_list = [
{'Вопрос 1': 'Ответ 1', 'Вопрос 2': 'Ответ 2', 'Вопрос 3': 'Ответ 3'},
{'Вопрос 4': 'Ответ 4', 'Вопрос 5': 'Ответ 5', 'Вопрос 6': 'Ответ 6'},
{'Вопрос 7': 'Ответ 7', 'Вопрос 8': 'Ответ 8', 'Вопрос 9': 'Ответ 9'}
]
request = 'Вопрос 5'

for d in qa_list:
    for k,v in d.items():
        if request in k or request in v:
            print(k, v)
```

Вывод:

```
Вопрос 5 Ответ 5
```

Comment: Да, спасибо так и нужно! Только это все у меня идёт в обёртке телеграм бота, где необходимо всё это записать одной строкой. Не могли бы Вы подсказать как это перевести в код одной строки?

Comment: @PavloG, можно оформить нужный вам кусок кода как функцию и вызывать эту функцию ;)

Comment: Спасибо, не подумал)

Answer (score 4):

Можно воспользоваться модулем [dpath](https://pypi.org/project/dpath/) для поиска в словарях любой степени вложенности:

```
In [8]: import dpath.util as dpu

In [9]: data = {'Категория 1': {'Вопрос 1': 'Ответ 1', 'Вопрос 2': 'Ответ 2', 'Вопрос 3': 'Ответ 3', 'Вопрос 4': 'Ответ 4', 'Вопрос 5': 'Ответ 5'}, 'Категория 2': {'Вопрос 6
   ...: ': 'Ответ 6', 'Вопрос 7': 'Ответ 7', 'Вопрос 8': 'Ответ 8', 'Вопрос 9': 'Ответ 9', 'Вопрос 10': 'Ответ 10'}, 'Категория 3': {'Вопрос 11': 'Ответ 11', 'Вопрос 12': 'О
   ...: твет 12', 'Вопрос 13': 'Ответ 13', 'Вопрос 14': 'Ответ 14', 'Вопрос 15': 'Ответ 15'}}

In [10]: q = 'Вопрос 10'

In [11]: dpu.values(data, f"/**/{q}")
Out[11]: ['Ответ 10']

In [12]: dpu.values(data, f"/**/BLAH-BLAH-BLAH")
Out[12]: []
```

если нужен полный путь:

```
In [13]: dpu.search(data, f"/**/{q}")
Out[13]: {'Категория 2': {'Вопрос 10': 'Ответ 10'}}
```